# Android TimePicker not displayed well on landscape mode

Tags: android, api, mobile, landscape, timepicker

I'm currently building an app targeting API 23, with a minimum API 16.
I'm facing an issue where a TimePicker is displayed within an AlertDialog. The display looks fine on Portrait mode and on Landscape mode when launching the app on Nexus 5 API <=22. However, when launching the app on a Nexus 5 API 23, the landscape mode does not correctly display the TimePicker widget, it displays only its background colors.

- On Nexus 5 API 23 (Portrait):
  [TimePicker on Portrait mode (API 23)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJQOk.png)
- On Nexus 5 API 23 (Landscape):
  [TimePicker on Landscape mode (API 23)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKbeU.png)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to fix this display issue? I'm facing that only on M.

Answer (score 6):

You have to remove set title from time picker dialogue after that you will see time picker dialogue in Nexus 5. This issue is posted on google forum see below link :

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=201766

```
 TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;

        String[] time = txtTimeWriteOut.getText().toString().trim().split(":");
        int hour = Integer.parseInt(time[0]);
        int minute = Integer.parseInt(time[1]);

        mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {

                txtTimeWriteOut.setText(TimeUtils.getDoubleDigits(selectedHour) + ":" + TimeUtils.getDoubleDigits(selectedMinute));

                passTimeOut = currentDate + TimeUtils.getDoubleDigits(selectedHour) + TimeUtils.getDoubleDigits(selectedMinute) + "00";

            }
        }, hour, minute, true);

//        mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
        mTimePicker.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

I have this issue.
This help for me:

```
timePicker.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: Problem in timePicker size.

Comment: Where you are calling this method? In `onCreate()`?

Comment: Yes. 
After some time, I found more correct solution. Try set minimum height for time picker, but i don't remember exact value or wrap datepicker in scrollview and set for timePicker height and width values wrap_content.

Comment: TimePicker wrong displayed when his real height less some value. Maybe when height less 495dp bit its not not exactly value.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comments. I'll let you know how it will turn out for me. Maybe I'll even put my answer here.

Answer (score 1):

### 1. If you DON'T care about loosing the title on your dialog:

If you are strictly following the [official documentation on Pickers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html), here is what you have to do in your `onCreateDialog()` method:

Instead of creating  new instance of `TimePickerDialog` and returning it straight away, call `setTitle(null)` on it before you return it, like so:

```
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    /* ... */

    Dialog dialogFragment = new TimePickerDialog(/* ... */);
    dialogFragment.setTitle(null);
    return dialogFragment;
}
```

---

I would like to note, that the problem was not occurring on Android 5.0.2 (Lollipop). The dialog was without the title by default.

The problem occurred on Android 6.0 device. It displayed the very same dialog with a title.

### 2. If having the title on the dialog is a must for you:

You should read the source code for [TimePickerDialog](http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/TimePickerDialog.java). No other way around.
I didn't go full rage-mode on the source code, since I had the luxury of just setting it to `null`.

I believe you can find a private method `setupTitle()` of the package-private class [AlertController](http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/support/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/app/AlertController.java#mTitleView) very interesting. `AlertControler` is used in [AlertDialog](http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/support/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/app/AlertDialog.java#mAlert) business logic.